# How do I remove an item from an array based on the difference between two items

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to remove outliers from a dataset, where an outlier is if the difference between one item and the next one is larger than 3 * the uncertainty on the item

```
def remove_outliers(data):
    for i in data:
        x = np.where(abs(i[1] - (i+1)[1]) > 3(  * data[:,2]))
        data_outliers_removed = np.delete(data, x, axis =1)
        return data_outliers_removed
```

is the function which I tried to use, however it either deletes no values or all values when I've played around with it.

Answer (score 0):

i would maybe do something like this by working with a new empty array.

```
def remove_outliers(dataset):
filtered_dataset = []
for index, item in enumerate(dataset):
    if index == 0:
        filtered_dataset.append(item)
    else:
        if abs(item[0] - dataset[index - 1][0]) <= 3 * dataset[index - 1][1]:
            filtered_dataset.append(item)
return filtered_dataset
```

Of course the same can be achieved easily with numpy.
Hope that helps

Comment: Iterating over a numpy array is usually a code-smell, since you reject numpy's super-fast indexing and slicing abilities for python's slow loops.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a numpy array is usually a code-smell, since you reject numpy's super-fast indexing and slicing abilities for python's slow loops. I'm assuming `data` is a numpy array since you've used it like one.

Your criterion for an outlier is:

> if the difference between one item and the next one is larger than 3 * the uncertainty on the item

From your usage, it appears the "items" are in the `data[:, 1]` column, and the uncertainties are in the `data[:, 2]` column.

The difference between an item and the next one is easy to obtain using [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), so our condition becomes:

```
np.diff(data[:, 1]) > 3 * data[:-1, 2]
```

I skipped the last uncertainty by doing `data[:-1, 2]` because the last uncertainty doesn't matter -- the last item doesn't have a "next element". I'm going to consider that it is an outlier and filter it out, but I've also shown how to filter it in if you want.

We will use [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to filter out the rows we don't want in our array:

```
def remove_outliers(data):
    select_mask = np.zeros(data[:, 1].shape, dtype=bool) # Make an array of Falses
    # Since the default value of the mask is False, items are considered outliers
    # and therefore filtered out unless we calculate the value for the mask
    # If you want to consider the opposite, do `np.ones(...)`

    # Only calculate the value for the mask for the first through the second-last item
    select_mask[:-1] = np.diff(data[:, 1]) > 3 * data[:-1, 2]

    # Select only those rows where select_mask is True
    # And select all columns
    filtered_data = data[select_mask, :] 
    return filtered_data
```